# Header Footer in HTTP Header : PHP to Word file

Tags: php, html, ms-word

I use following HTTP Header to get a Word Document from a PHP file.

```
 <?php
 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");    
 echo "<html>";
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; 
                                               charset=Windows-1252\">";
 echo "<body>";
 echo "<b>My first document</b>";
 echo "</body>";
 echo "</html>";
 ?>
```

I would like to have Header and Footer & Page Break in the resulting Document.

Help to fix it..

Comment: @Hashem I think the desired result will come only when the use of CSS that why i tagged it..

Comment: If it's a CSS issue, I'd better suggest you to post the HTML output instead of PHP code.